# Create a single object with a single texture from blend file including several materials

Tags: game-engine

I have a house with textures in a blend file. The house consists of a bunch of different objects also including different materials/textures and i want to create a single textured object to import into a game. The textures doesnt show up in blender render i dont know why but maybe this is my problem.

I think baking is the way i have to go and followed a tutorial on how to bake a texture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7bjdWu9OGs but without the result. Cant i do that with cycles rendering or havent i followed the tutorial correct?

Answer (score 1):

Blender internal and cycles do not use the same materials. You can bake a cycles material to an image texture and then create a blender internal material that uses that image.

Also look at the [texture atlas addon](https://www.blendernation.com/2012/09/13/textureatlas-add-on-baking-entire-scenes/) to merge all objects onto one image texture.